# HTML <input> elements of type url let enter non-url

Tags: html

I'm working on a side project to handle my bookmarks, stored through their urls. So I ended up with a form to add resources to my storage, something like:

```html
<form action="" method="get">
  <input type="url" name="resource">
  <button type="submit">Add</button>
</form>
```

Then I wondered whether I could extend my project to store books through ISBN numbers. An ISBN number isn't an url (a unique location), but an [urn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Name) (a unique name, e.g. `urn:isbn:000-0-0000-0000-0`). So my input should be of type [uri](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Identifier), to cover both cases.

Except there is no `uri` type for HTML `<input>`. Feeling frustration, I tried to enter an ISBN urn in my input of type url and clicked on "Add" to see the validation error... but it worked!

Is this a bug or a feature?

(I tried with both firefox and chrome)

Comment: Why not use RegExp to validate user's input?

Comment: This is an expected behavior but input will eventually expect a url according to w3 https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/sec-forms.html#url-state-typeurl

Answer (score -1):

No it is really a bug and not a feature because url only accepts url and cannot accept uri or urn